# iOS Back button item not showing custom image after MacOS update

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a piece of code in my project that sets the back button item of a navigation item to a custom image, like this:

```
class BaseNavigationViewController: RTRootNavigationController {
    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "nav_back_icon"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
}
```

This code has been working fine for the past six months, and the custom back button item was displayed properly. However, after I submitted a new version of the app and updated my MacOS, the back button item reverted to the default "Back" text.

I've tried using the leftBarButtonItem and gesture recognizers to achieve a similar functionality, but the exit animation and smoothness are not as satisfying as before.

I'm not sure what caused this issue as the code related to the back button item hasn't been changed in the past year, and there were no modifications made to this code in the recent update.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

I am trying to replace the backBarButtonItem in my navigation controller with a custom gesture recognizer. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
class BaseNavigationViewController: RTRootNavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let edgePanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleEdgePanGesture(_:)))
        edgePanGesture.edges = .left
        edgePanGesture.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(edgePanGesture)
    }

    @objc private func handleEdgePanGesture(_ gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard gesture.state == .recognized else {
            return
        }
        popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1 && !navigationBar.isHidden
    }
}
```

However, the animation provided by this code is not quite what I'm looking for. I have tried using leftBarButtonItem and other methods to achieve the same functionality, but the exit animation and smoothness are not as satisfactory as before.

I'm not sure what changes may have caused this issue to arise, as the backBarButtonItem code has not been modified recently. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions for how to achieve the desired animation with a custom gesture recognizer?